# How to know title input based on non special character with multiform (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, text, input, title

How we can validate multi title input form based on non special character or not with javascript?

Its my script:

```
<? require "header.php"; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#filealt[i]").keypress(function(event){
    var ew = event.which;
    if(ew == 32)
    return true;
    if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
        return true;
    if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
        return true;
    if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
        return true;
    return false; 
});
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="filealt0" name="filealt0" class="input2" maxlength="70">
<input type="text" id="filealt1" name="filealt1" class="input2" maxlength="70">
<input type="text" id="filealt2" name="filealt2" class="input2" maxlength="70">
<? require "footer.php"; ?>
```

Updated (09/08/14):

I mean `$("#filealt[i]")` from multiple id (filealt0-filealt2) and I can't figure it to select mulitple ID.

Comment: `$("#filealt[i]")` <- that's an error, you have no elements matching that ID

Comment: @adeneo Sorry I mean `$("#filealt[i]")` from ID filealt0-filealt2 and I want validate all text input with select all id filealt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) jquery selector:

```
$("input[id^='filealt']").keypress(function(event){ // Your code
```

It selects all inputs with ids starting with `filealt`.
Here is working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YjeULa?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, wrong selector try `[id^='filealt']`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `"#filealt[i]"` is a valid jQuery selector or what it does. What I would do is instead use a common class on all your inputs like `my-class`.

Also, you would probably need to wrap you jQuery code in a document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my-class").keypress(function(event){
        var ew = event.which;
        if(ew == 32)
            return true;
        if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
            return true;
        if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
            return true;
        if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
            return true;
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $("#filealt[i]")
> ```

You don't have any element with the id `filealt[i]` (your selector would need to be `"#filealt1, #filealt2, #filealt3"`, or be constructed within a loop). Instead, use the class as a selector:

```
$(".input2").…
```